# Creating a Search Query with TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a search query that I need to create to pull some records from my table. There are 4 fields that you can search by: deliveryDate, dueDate, employee, status

I need to figure out how to create a search where the results will include any one of those pieces of information.

Would it be using the OR operator in the where clause?

```
WHERE A.[status] = @statusSearch 
  OR  A.[dueDate] = @dueDateSearch 
  OR  A.[deliveryDate] = @deliverDateSearch
  OR  A.[empID] = @empSearch
```

Comment: That query looks fine.

Comment: What should happen when multiple filter conditions are entered?

Comment: I just want it to pull any records that have information that was entered into the option search fields.

Comment: This is not an SQL problem, but a requirements problem. Using OR or AND changes the result. You need to understand what the user expects to find by filling in more than one search field. You also need to handle empty search fields.

Comment: Frazz - What is the best way to handl ethis then? All 4 of the search fields are optional so they could enter an employee name and see all records with that person in it or a due date with a stauts of pending and see all of those results

Comment: I usually use dynamic SQL, built client side, with just the WHERE clauses corresponding to the search fields that have been filled in. Another solution is to have slightly more complex SQL, but static. The former requires more code but provides more efficient SQL statements than the latter.

Comment: Should something like this work?

`WHERE (@dueDateSearch IS null OR A.[dueDate] = @dueDateSearch) OR 
    (@deliveryDateSearch IS null OR A.[dateDelivered] = @deliveryDateSearch) OR
    (@empSearch IS null OR A.[empID] = @empSearch) AND A.[status] = @statusSearch  `

Comment: That is the idea. But as I said, it would be more efficient to build a statement that just contains the parts required by the fields the user filled out.

Answer (score 0):

If the input parameters are optional, then you need to use a different logic that will accept inputs for search only when a valid data is provided else it will not consider the input for the filter

```
WHERE 

(
A.[status] = @statusSearch 

OR 

@statusSearch = ''

)

AND

(

A.[dueDate] = @dueDateSearch

OR

@dueDateSearch = ''

)

AND

( 

A.[deliveryDate] = @deliverDateSearch

OR

@deliverDateSearch = ''

)

AND

(

A.[empID] = @empSearch

OR

@empSearch = ''

)
```